# Float counter order doesn't match display order

Tags: floats, numbering, positioning

I have a problem with the `H` placement option of the `float` package. This option allows 'real' floats to float past it, but the reference counter is not adjusted. In the MWE below, I would like to give the first appearing figure (which is second in the source) the counter 1 instead of 2, and vice versa. I do not want to change the order of appearance. I also do not want to manually set the counter. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\fbox{this is the first figure in the source}
\caption{First in the source}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\fbox{this is the second figure in the source}
\caption{Second in the source}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX tries hard to give good spacing and good numbering for floats, but using `[H]` opts out of that mechanism so you need to take care of both numbering and spacing by hand (or not using `H` is often better)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\fbox{this is the first figure in the source}
\addtocounter{figure}{1}
\caption{First in the source}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\fbox{this is the second figure in the source}
\addtocounter{figure}{-2}
\caption{Second in the source}
\addtocounter{figure}{2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Clearly any such adjustments to the numbering should be left until the very end of the document, when you know the final location of the figures.